# How to get the specific value from Firebase database inside OnMarkerClickListener?

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database

I am getting the data from firebase database and showing the markers on the map. 
I am having trouble in getting the value from firebase when I query from inside the OnMarkerClickListener.
What I want to do is get the id of the specific marker from the database and then save it in a String and send that String to the another activity through intent. 
Everything is working fine, I'm just having trouble in getting the id from the database inside the OnMarkerClickListener.
Here's the code.

```
public class NearbyEventsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    String selectedCategory;

    List<Event> eventList;

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
    Marker marker;

    LocationManager manager;
    Criteria mCriteria;
    String bestProvider;
    Location mLocation;

    String eventid, eventTitle;

    FirebaseAuth auth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference eventRef;
    Query query, q;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nearby_events);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Nearby Events");

        selectedCategory = getIntent().getStringExtra("selectedCategory");

        eventList = new ArrayList<>();

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        eventRef = database.getReference("events");

        query = database.getReference("events")
                .orderByChild("event_category")
                .equalTo(selectedCategory);


        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);

        Dexter.withActivity(this)
                .withPermissions(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                        // check if all permissions are granted
                        if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            // do you work now
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                                        checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                    // TODO: Consider calling
                                    //    Activity#requestPermissions
                                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                                    // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                            mMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
                            mMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
                            mMap.setIndoorEnabled(true);
                            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

                        }

                        // check for permanent denial of any permission
                        if (report.isAnyPermissionPermanentlyDenied()) {
                            // permission is denied permenantly, navigate user to app settings
                            showSettingsDialog();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).onSameThread().check();

        // when map gets ready, set the camera to current location of the user.
        manager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mCriteria = new Criteria();
        bestProvider = String.valueOf(manager.getBestProvider(mCriteria, true));
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    Activity#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for Activity#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
        }
        mLocation = manager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
        if (mLocation != null) {
            Log.e("TAG", "GPS is on");
            final double currentLatitude = mLocation.getLatitude();
            final double currentLongitude = mLocation.getLongitude();
            LatLng loc1 = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc1).title("Your Current Location"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude), 15));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11), 2000, null);
        }

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                eventList.clear();
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Event event = snapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                        eventList.add(event);

                        for (int i = 0; i < eventList.size(); i++) {
                            Event mEvent = eventList.get(i);

                            Double lat = mEvent.getLat();
                            Double lng = mEvent.getLng();

                            LatLng loc = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(loc).title(mEvent.getEvent_title()))
                                    .setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

                eventTitle = marker.getTitle();

                q = database.getReference("events")
                        .orderByChild("event_title")
                        .equalTo(eventTitle);

                q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Event e = snapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                            eventid = e.getEvent_id();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });

                Intent intent = new Intent(NearbyEventsActivity.this, EventDetailActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("eventid", eventid);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);

                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        return false;
    }

    private void showSettingsDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(NearbyEventsActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Need Permissions");
        builder.setMessage("This app needs permission to use this feature. You can grant them in app settings.");
        builder.setPositiveButton("GOTO SETTINGS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
                openSettings();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

    }

    private void openSettings() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
        intent.setData(uri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
    }

}
```

My firebase database is just just like the normal database

```
events
   -Lp08gX8tEQBjXIGwm
      - event_title : "Abc"
      - event_id : "Lp08gX8tEQBjXIGwm"
      . . .
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a JSON file or at least as a screenshot. Beside that, what do you mean through "just having trouble in getting the id from the database inside the OnMarkerClickListener"?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like till the time you get event id,your EventDetailActivity is started already.
so try to Log the eventid inside forloop and start EventDetailActivity inside onDataChange method.

```
q.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Event e = snapshot.getValue(Event.class);
                        eventid = e.getEvent_id();
                        Log.v("eventid",eventid);
                    }

                   Intent intent = new Intent(NearbyEventsActivity.this, 
                   EventDetailActivity.class);
                   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                   bundle.putString("eventid", eventid);
                   intent.putExtras(bundle);
                   startActivity(intent);

                }
```

Comment: you were right, the activity starts before the value is fetched. I added the code if(eventid != null) { startActivity(intent); }  and on first tap it doesn't open the activity but on second tap it open it up fine. What can be done to solve the problem?

Comment: you have to debug and check if you get eventid on first tap or not